# Can't install Windows Updates - Error Code 800706F7 (No KB3004394 update installed)

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, windows-update

Since the turn of the year, my PC hasn't been able to install any Windows Updates, outputting error `800706F7`. Searching around suggests it's to do with `KB3004394` and that I should uninstall it; however, this update doesn't appear to be installed when looking in *View Installed Updates*.

- After running `sfc /scannow`, the `CBS.log` says the problem is `crypt32.dll` and that it cannot repair it.

  - I tried replacing it with the copy from my Windows 7 install disc via `cmd`, but this hasn't solved my problem; due to this, I am unable to use VirtualBox since it states this file is causing an error that prevents the Virtual Machines from opening
- Oracle suggests VirtualBox is unable to verify this file and that `KB3004394` didn't install the Windows 7 x64 catalog `package_1_for_KB3004394~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.3.1.0.cat`, which is used to verify `crypt32.dll`

The majority of suggestions relating to error `800706F7` and a corrupt `crypt32.dll`is to remove that update, which I can't since it's not installed, and have even used the Windows Update that specifically removes `KB3004394` just to make sure.

How do I troubleshoot and fix this?

Comment: Are you running a legit version of Windows 7 on your virtualbox?

Comment: @Reeves I am running a legit version of Windows 7 64-bit Professional downloaded through my University's DreamSpark. I have had it since October 2013 with no issues. I am trying to use Linux on my VirtualBox, but I can't start the machine. Both VirtualBox and Windows 7 are being affected by this crypt32.dll file.

Comment: You've probably checked this site, but: http://pcsupport.about.com/od/findbyerrormessage/a/crypt32-dll-not-found-missing-error.htm has everything you should need. If nothing there works, backup and wipe/reload. Maybe someone else will come along with more help...

Comment: repair your Windows via Inpalce upgrade: http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/3413-repair-install.html

Comment: [I would install this patch anyway](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3024777)

Comment: This sounds like a Component Store [`%WinDir%\WinSxS`] issue... please try the steps in [this](https://superuser.com/a/1600121/529800) answer. _(Just an FYI, you cannot blindly replace files in `%WinDir%` from an `install.esd`/`install.wim` as it breaks hardlinks in the Component Store)_

Answer (score 1):

After removing some Windows shortcuts from the Start menu, I had a similar issue. Some shortcuts and folders, such as *Administrative Tools* and *Accessories* are required or update fails, see [Error with Windows Update](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows8_1-windows_update/error-with-windows-update-kb3000850/b0e3fa91-5f31-4258-998a-1d0dff88a37e?page=2), [Problems renaming Windows Accessories](http://www.postseek.com/meta/29f9213583a73546dc720adb8371f5e4) and [Issue installing...](http://www.dslreports.com/forum/r28474423-Issue-installing-MS13-054). If anyone has a complete list of required  Start menu folders and shortcuts, please add it to this answer.

Also, if there are incomplete updates, the botched files need to be removed; see [Repairing the Windows 7 Update Folder](http://smallbusiness.chron.com/repairing-windows-7-update-folder-location-70148.html).

Hopefully, the updates should take care of the invalid crypt32.dll.