# What effect does the Windows Build # Have on DISM Restore?

Tags: windows-10, dism

I've been researching DISM functionality and I've read several articles, such as:

- https://www.windowscentral.com/how-use-dism-command-line-utility-repair-windows-10-image
- https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/repair-a-windows-image
- [How will DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth affect my current configuration?](https://superuser.com/q/1330365/1272384)

It is my understanding that, if I am specifying a WIM in the /Source parameter, the WIM needs to match the same version, edition, and language of Windows that's currently running on the machine that will be repaired.

What I'm wondering is, how does the Build # play into this? For example, let's say I am running 1909 build 18363.1316, does the source WIM that I am repairing from also need to be build 18363.1316? It would seem to make sense that this is the case, but I have not found any documentation specifying this.

Answer (score 0):

For the first Creator Update (Version 1703), there was (could have been on your machine) a mis-match in the image needed and what was on the machine.  To correct that mis-match:

> If DISM will not run (mismatch) go to Microsoft Tech Bench and
> download the 64-bit English ISO Burn the ISO to a DVD so as to see all
> the files.  First mount the file as follows: DISM.exe /Mount-Wim
> /WimFile:C:\test\images\myimage.wim /index:1
> /MountDir:C:\test\offline Then run the DISM command

That was indeed very picky and error-prone to work through.

Prior to V1703 my recollection is that Repair worked but I have no documentation that far back.

Since (about) V18xx (a while back now), for Windows 10 Home and Windows 10 Pro, the image required for DISM to work successfully has always been included and correct. That is, if DISM could run (no errors preventing it from running) then it would and does now run successfully.

> It is my understanding that, if I am specifying a WIM in the /Source
> parameter, the WIM needs to match the same version, edition, and
> language of Windows that's currently running on the machine that will
> be repaired.

Yes. That is correct if you wish to specify manually. And since Windows 10 V18xx, Home and Pro, this has always been automatic and true so that users and businesses can readily repair these machines.

Also, there is a limit to what DISM can repair. It repairs (replaces) components found in the Windows 10 storage location.

However there are numerous errors that need to be repaired with a Windows 10 Repair Install

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Even then, a damaged User Profile can only be fixed by replacing the User Profile (and oftimes by reinstalling Windows).

Comment: At the end of the day the .WIM must contain the appropriate image.  While the version of DISM should match it doesn’t necessarily need to match.  Obviously newer versions of DISM will have more capabilities potentially

Comment: So, just to get some further clarification... the build # would be irrelevant? So as long as the edition, version (i.e. 1909, 2004, etc.), and language match, the OS build won't matter?

Comment: From V18xx and forward for Home and Pro, DISM has always worked using the "online" image on the particular computer being repaired, so from V18xx , yes, the build does not matter. It has always worked here.

Comment: @Daniel - It’s not irrelevant

Comment: Please advise me if you wish the answer to be deleted. It appears that may be the case but I am not certain.

Comment: Hi @John ... If you are talking to me, I have no opinion with this regard. I removed the comment. My comment was more for the other comments and not your answer as I have no opinion with this regard because I have very little knowledge with WIM at the moment. That was more a comment on the other comment(s) but I removed it in case you were asking me. I would suspect some downvotes if someone thought you should delete but I'm not certain. I was talking more about the version and the proceeding build minor numbers and such and correlated features and functions thereof only.

Comment: I was not aiming my comment at you :)  I was just wondering out loud.